# How can I compress a pdf in a different directory using ghostscript command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, terminal, ghostscript

How can I compress a pdf in a different directory using the command below?:

```
ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

/books/input.pdf instead of input.pdf Doesn't compress the input.pdf which is in the `/books` directory.

I am using ghostscript4js in my node app to compress pdf using the commands but the pdf needs to be at the same directory as the server.js file to be able to compress it. Since I want to keep my pdfs in a separate directory (i.e. /books) I wonder how can I do that?
And also can I output into a different directory?

Comment: Ghostscript (more properly the pdfwrite device) doesn't compress PDF files, it creates them. The new PDF file **may** be smaller than the original input depending on a number of factors. There is no executable called 'ghostscript'. Ghostscript binary executables are named gs, gswinxx or gswinxxc (where xx is the word size). Given the path separator you are using (/) it seems likely you are on a Linux or MacOS system. Do you really have a directory at the root level called 'books' ? Or is that a sub-directory from the current ? If the latte either use proper syntax (eg ./books) or a full path.

Comment: Thnks! I put absolute path and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

/books/input.pdf won't work, what I should have used is `./books/input.pdf`.